# Panda dataframe Json flattening for all rows

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have below Panda Dataframe where there are three records.

[image]

I am able to do the JSON flattening using only one row at a time, but I try for all rows it doesn't work.
JSON flattening for single row.

[image]

For all rows I need help as below code is not working at all for me
[image]

My Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['data'],
    data=[
        [{ "answers_interface": { "__id": 1, "flags": {}, "heloc": 3 ,"balloon": 4 }}],
        [{ "answers_interface": { "__id": 2, "flags": {}, "heloc": 3, "balloon": 4 }}]
    ])
```

Comment: post the first 3 rows as text.

Comment: Thanks @enke I have added the dataset in the question. here I am also adding `df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['data'],
    data=[
        [{ "answers_interface": { "__id": 1, "flags": {}, "heloc": 3 ,"balloon": 4 }}],
        [{ "answers_interface": { "__id": 2, "flags": {}, "heloc": 3, "balloon": 4 }}]
    ])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `df['data']` to list, then use `json_normalize`:

```
out = pd.json_normalize(df['data'].tolist())
```

Output:

```
   answers_interface.__id  answers_interface.heloc  answers_interface.balloon
0                       1                        3                          4
1                       2                        3                          4
```

Comment: Thanks its working fine , I was doing mistake by not converting to list.